# garbage collection and reference counting

Tags: python

This is easily the weirdest bug I've run into in a while. Let me give you a snippet of the code I'm working with. This code accesses a few Django apis, but those aren't particularly important to what's going on (I hope).

```
def handle_location(self):
    zip_code_location = Location.objects.filter(zip_code=self.cleaned_data.get('zip_code'))

    if not zip_code_location:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid zip code returned.', code='invalid_zip_code')
    else:
        zip_code_location = zip_code_location[0]

    city, state = map(lambda x: x.strip().lower(), self.cleaned_data.get('location_raw').split(','))

    try:
        city_state_location = map_citystate_to_location(city, state)
    except LocationMatchingException as e:
        logging.error(e.msg + 'location_raw: {} and zip_code: {}'.format(self.cleaned_data.get('location'),
                                                                         self.cleaned_data('zip_code'),
                                                                         exc_info=True, stack_info=True))

        raise forms.ValidationError('Something is wrong with that location!', code='invalid_location')

    # Compare these by zip code. We don't have an __eq__ operator overloaded
    if city_state_location.zip_code != zip_code_location.zip_code:
        logging.error('The zipcode returned from the client mapped to a different location than the raw city and'
                      'state returned from the client. \n'
                      'location_raw: {} \n'
                      'location matched with zip_code: {} \n'
                      'location matched with city and state: {}'.format(self.cleaned_data.get('location'),
                                                                        zip_code_location,
                                                                        city_state_location,
                                                                        exc_info=True, stack_info=True))
        forms.ValidationError('Something is wrong with that location!', code='invalid_location')

    self.cleaned_data['location'] = zip_code_location
```

We create a variable called zip_code_location at the very beginning and assign it a Location object. The Location object is a fairly simple class that inherits form Django.db.models.model. It does nothing out of the ordinary as far as Django goes. Anyhow, we store our zip_code_location in a dictionary called cleaned_data and go on our merry way.

The function handle_location is called by a function called clean. Normally if I check the value of cleaned_data from within clean, it looks like this:

```
{'start_time': datetime.time(1, 57), 'location_raw': 'Manhattan bch, CA', 'start_date': datetime.date(2014, 10, 28), 'payment_method': 'G', 'zip_code': '90266', 'price': 2324.0, 'title': 'asdsadds', 'location': <Location: manhattan beach, ca 90266 -- lat: 33.88 long: -118.40 -- population 30505>, 'start_datetime': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 28, 8, 57, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'type': 'T'}
```

Notice that the location is there. I found one particular location where this isn't the case. The key/value pair exists inside self.cleaned_data as program leaves handle_location but then completely disappears as we hit the return statement and move up the stack.  What the heck???? It's almost like the garbage collector decided that there were no more references to the original instance pointed to by zip_code_location and decided to clean it up. But clearly this shouldn't be the case. Anyone have any idea what's happening?  And why it might apply to certain inputs?

Thank you for any insight

Nick

EDIT: I was wrong. The key/value pair doesn't disappear when we go up the stack, it just never gets assigned to self.cleaned_data in the first place. When I step through the code in the debugger and check the value of cleaned_data on the line reading "return," it doesn't contain a "location" key. Could there be a Set property that is causing the dict to reject my input?

Comment: I assume you provided the whole method `handle_location` not only parts of it? I don't see a `return` statement so when speak about `return`, do you mean the implicit one after `self.cleaned_data['location'] = zip_code_location`? If the key `'location'` is missing in the dictionary this means you never reached the line of this last assignment. Are you sure that there is no exception raised? Do you call this method maybe within a `try` clause? And by the way you might want to `raise` the `ValidationError` in the last `if` clause.

Comment: I think the return statement got cut off. It is immediately after we set self.cleaned_data['location']. I think I figured out there error. I steppe through the code using PDB and actually got different results than when using Pycharm's debugger. Long story short, I think the Pycharm debugger lieing to be about my location in the code